# flutter google_maps can't zoom out any further

Tags: flutter, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-flutter

As the picture below, I've been searching everywhere about this issue but still cant find any solution.

About my code, i use the very default sample from **google_maps_flutter**, but it still doesnt let me zoom out any further from my default latitude/longitude.

**(It is not about my internet connection, it remains the same)**

```
GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        // circles: _circles,
        markers: {
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("123"),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Carin"),
            position: LatLng(-6.915601, 107.591446),
          )
        },
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller = controller;
          //_controller!.setMapStyle(MapStyle().dark);
        },
      )
```

I've been trying to clean, clean cache, restart the emulator, but the problem still there. And the main problem is, the map container shows blank/black screen on real device.

When i opened the page which contains google maps, the console gives me **exceeded sample count in FrameTime** everytime i interact with the map, such as move or zoom in/out.

I really appreciate of any of your comments that trying to help, cuz i dont usually ask question if im not feeling totally stucked from everywhere, thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: What is your `_kGooglePlex` initialCameraPosition?